# finding the area limited by functions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Find $\int\int_{A}yda $ whereas $A$ is the area between $y=0$, $y^2=4x$, $y^2=5-x$

So I found the domain:

[image]

is the integral $\int_{4x}^{1}\int_{0}^{2}ydydx+\int_{1}^{x-5}\int_{0}^{2}ydxdy$?

Comment: Your bounds of integration don't seem to be right.

Comment: @HenryW. first I need to divide it to 2 integrals? because until  $(1,2)$ $y^2=4x$ is the upper limit and after that it is $y^2=5-x$?

Comment: The bounded region is $y$-simple, so one double integral is enough.

Comment: @HenryW. maybe $\int_{0}^{2}\int_{4x}^{5-x}y dx dy$?

Comment: You'll want fixed bounds for $y$ (indeed: 0 to 2) and then variable bounds for $x$, but that requires _$x$ as a function of $y$_...! Rewrite the equations so they're in the form $x=f(y)$; blue will be the bottom one and purple the upper boundary.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{2}\int_{\frac{y^2}{4}}^{5-y^2}y dx dy$?

Comment: Looks good! If they mean the bounded region where $y \ge 0$, because the given curves also bound a region where $y \le 0$ (so in fact the region $A$ is not clearly defined).

Comment: @StackTD that's right, but maybe because of symmetry is does not matter?

Comment: The area is the same but the integral also depends on the function you integrate (in this case: $y$). I assume they intended $A$ to be the upper region, with $y \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ means only upper area,
\begin{align}
\iint_A y dA &= \int_0^1 \int_{0}^{2\sqrt{x}} y dydx + \int_1^5 \int_{0}^{\sqrt{5-x}}y dydx\\
&=\int_0^1\left[\frac{1}{2}y^2\right]_0^{2\sqrt{x}}dx + \int_1^5\left[\frac{1}{2}y^2\right]_0^{\sqrt{5-x}}dx\\
&=\int_0^1 2x dx+\int_1^5 \frac{5-x}{2}dx\\
&=\left[x^2\right]_0^1 +\left[\frac{5}{2}x -\frac{1}{4}x^2\right]_1^5\\
&= 1 +\left(\frac{25}{2}-\frac{25}{4}\right)-\frac{9}{4}\\
&=5
\end{align}

**Alternative Method**: Calculate $$\int_0^2\int_{\frac{1}{4}y^2}^{5-y^2}ydxdy$$and get same result.